# Obvious inequality

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are Lebesgue integrable functions on $E$. Then:

$$ \int\limits_E | f + g | \leq \int\limits_E ( |f| + |g| ) $$

Does this follow easily? I can see we have to use the triangle inequality, but does it work even with integrals? I'm not seeing this inequality.

Comment: Monotonicity of the integral? :)

Comment: It follows directly from the definition of the Lebesgue integral for non-negative measurable functions that if $a,b$ are measurable with $0 \leqslant a \leqslant b$, then $\int a \leqslant \int b$. Pick $a = \lvert f+g\rvert$ and $b = \lvert f\rvert + \lvert g\rvert$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course $|f+g| \leq |f|+|g|$ and integral is monotone, so yeah
$$\int\limits_E | f + g | \leq \int\limits_E ( |f| + |g| )$$

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little easier to understand if we make use of the linearity of the integral.

$$ \int\limits_E ( |f| + |g| ) - \int\limits_E | f + g | = \int\limits_E ( |f| + |g| ) - | f + g | $$

Since $A \le B$ precisely when $B-A \ge 0$, the final step is realizing that integral on the right hand side above is nonnegative (because the integrand is nonnegative, by virtue of triangle inequality).  This latter observation amounts to monotonicity of integration.